# Pyspark timestamp format changes after saving to csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which contains a timestamp column. When I display the df I see the values as:

[image]

But when I save the df to csv I see the values as:

[image]

I have tried both the options `timestampFormat` and `dateformat` but still the same.

```
q.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").save("/test_dhs/")

q.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").save("/test_dhs/")
```

Background:

```
q=spark.read.parquet("/eureka/dhs_aco_ovrvw_000.parquet")
```

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdQh9.png)

[sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1fdE.png)

Comment: Can you provide some minimal code that describes the starting dataset? Even few rows are fine, just to know we're in the same context.

Comment: @soatz.I have added some extra info.

Comment: Which version of pyspark are you using?

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.